# Sum of missing data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The below query displays sites against the total orders within last week.
But if there is no order for a given site in last week, i should still see the site with a sum of zero.
At the moment its only giving me four sites, thats because no order has been made in the last week for those sites.

```
select SITE
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as COMPLETED
from 
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT ORDERS.SITE, ORDERS.ORDERDATE  FROM ORDERS
   INNER JOIN PHONEDATA AS P
   ON ORDERS.RECID = P.OrderID
   where SITE IN ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7')

) X
GROUP BY SITE
order by SITE
```

RESULT:

Site---------------------Completed

SITE1-----------------------2

SITE2-----------------------2

SITE3-----------------------2

SITE4-----------------------2

EXPECTED RESULT:

Site---------------------Completed

SITE1-----------------------2

SITE2-----------------------2

SITE3-----------------------2

SITE4-----------------------2

SITE5-----------------------0

SITE6-----------------------0

SITE7-----------------------0

updated:

```
select SITE
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as COMPLETED
from 
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT ORDERS.SITE, ORDERS.ORDERDATE  FROM ORDERS

   where SITE IN ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7')

) X
GROUP BY SITE
order by SITE
```

I have now removed the inner join with phone data table, so i am now getting the missing sites. but the reason i avoided this approach is because if i only rely on the orders table the orderdate time field is inserted few times for a given order, and the final order makes it to the phonedata table, so now i get more values in completed count but it should only consider the latest value for each day for each site

result of update :

Site---------------------Completed

SITE1-----------------------5

SITE2-----------------------5

SITE3-----------------------5

SITE4-----------------------5

SITE5-----------------------0

SITE6-----------------------0

SITE7-----------------------0

expected

Site---------------------Completed

SITE1-----------------------2

SITE2-----------------------2

SITE3-----------------------2

SITE4-----------------------2

SITE5-----------------------0

SITE6-----------------------0

SITE7-----------------------0

Comment: Do you have a table that identifies all the sites?

Comment: Could there legitimately be two orders for a site in a single day?  If so, your new method will miss them.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no rows in the table with the sites that have no orders, how can it return any rows to count?  Perhaps you have a table with all the possible sites that can be joined to?  Or create a temp table with the site values.  You could then left join the orders table to this.  i.e.

```
create table #sites (site varchar(25));
insert into #sites values ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7');
...
from 
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT ORDERS.SITE, ORDERS.ORDERDATE  FROM 
   #sites s left join ORDERS on orders.site = s.site
   INNER JOIN PHONEDATA AS P
   ON ORDERS.RECID = P.OrderID

) X
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join instead of the inner join. It is probably not getting rows from the phone data table:

```
select SITE
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as COMPLETED
from 
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT ORDERS.SITE, ORDERS.ORDERDATE  FROM ORDERS
   Left JOIN PHONEDATA AS P
   ON ORDERS.RECID = P.OrderID
   where SITE IN ('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3','SITE4','SITE5','SITE6','SITE7')

) X
GROUP BY SITE
order by SITE
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to start with a "Site" table and then left join to your results.  This example mimics the behavior, and can be used as a hack-workaround.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      site VARCHAR(10) ,
      Completed TINYINT
    )
INSERT  INTO @table
        ( site, Completed )
VALUES  ( 'SITE1', 0 ),
        ( 'SITE2', 0 ),
        ( 'SITE3', 0 ),
        ( 'SITE4', 0 ),
        ( 'SITE5', 0 ),
        ( 'SITE6', 0 ),
        ( 'SITE7', 0 )

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   SITE ,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN OrderDate >= DATEADD(dd,( DATEDIFF(dd, -53690, GETDATE() - 1) / 7 ) * 7, -53690)
                                 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                            END) AS COMPLETED
               FROM     ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                    ORDERS.SITE ,
                                    ORDERS.ORDERDATE
                          FROM      ORDERS
                                    INNER JOIN PHONEDATA AS P ON ORDERS.RECID = P.OrderID
                          WHERE     SITE IN ( 'SITE1', 'SITE2', 'SITE3',
                                              'SITE4', 'SITE5', 'SITE6',
                                              'SITE7' )
                        )
               GROUP BY SITE
             )
    SELECT  t.site ,
            t.completed + cte.COMPLETED
    FROM    @table t
            LEFT OUTER JOIN cte ON t.site = cte.Site
    ORDER BY t.site
```

Comment: i have update the question, please consider the updated question above